# Example of using jq-idealforms

Tags: jquery

Does anyone have a GOOD example for using all of the jq-idealforms components? I am having trouble getting it to work, even after using the demo page and reading the GitHub page. I would like a link to an open project or something that shows it in full use, or a really good tutorial that works!

Edit:
To be specific, when I am checking the form in the browser, I am getting 
`<span class="error hidden" style="display: none;">` 
for my select input. How do I make it so that the error is NOT hidden?

Answer (score 0):

So in case anyone stumbles onto this issue, the problem turns out to be that the validation messages used out-of-box with IdealForms conflicts with some of the CSS that comes with Bootstrap. I stopped the Bootstrap CSS from loading and everything worked fine!

I cannot say where the issue was exactly because I decided (for various reasons) to use the Foundation framework, which has Abide included so I no longer need IdealForms.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The "hidden" param is add by idealforms script, line 68 :

```
self._getField(this).find(self.opts.error).addClass('hidden');
```

I use my superpower : I have erased this line. It's working

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: do not use IF3 css and make your own css for the error class.